# How to install java runtime jre on Amazon EC2

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2

I want to install the latest JRE on an Amazon EC2 instance which is based out of the Amazon "Amazon Linux 2 LTS Candidate AMI 2017.12.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type" AMI.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download JRE (**jre-8u161-linux-x64.rpm**) for Linux (64) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html
2. SSH into your AMI with the .pem file that you created when Launching hte Instance (ssh ec2-user@AMI_ID -i Path_to_.pem_file.pem
3. Create a folder called software under **/opt** (**sudo mkdir software**).
4. Change the permissions of the folder (**sudo chmod -R 700 .**)
5. Use any sftp client (I used cyberduck on Mac) to login to your instance (Same SSH scredentials, pem file)
6. Copy your downloaded file into **/opt/software**
7. Navigate to the software folder and run (**sudo rpm -ivh jre-8u161-linux-x64.rpm**).
8. Check if java is installed by running **java -version**.

Comment: Do you consider 777 good advice ? To install a RPM /tmp should be sufficient

Comment: Changed it to 700, thanks! Yes, /tmp will also do.

Comment: If OpenJDK is fine (the question did not specify that the proprietary Oracle version is required), you should also be able to just `yum install` it from the normal repositories.